# Facebook like button count reset on server down?

Tags: facebook

Will the facebook like button count reset when the server goes down?

Answer (score 0):

No, Facebook keeps track of the amount of likes for your site

Comment: No it does not. It just tracks the URL you are pointing the Like button at